# IBM Cloud PHP Getting started tutorial - Error with "php composer.phar install"

Tags: php, ibm-cloud

I am trying to complete the IBM Cloud PHP Getting started tutorial at [this](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/runtimes/php/getting-started.html#getting_started) on a Windows 10 machine.

I tried using PHP 7.3 (7.3.2) (download file name is php-7.3.2-nts-Win32-VC15-x64.zip).

I had already installed "The VC15 builds require to have the Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2017 x64" (vc_redist.x64.exe)

In step 2,

```
php composer.phar install
```

I get the error

```
C:\temp\get-started-php>php composer.phar install Loading composer repositories with package information Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file 

[ErrorException] "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"? 

install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
```

I have reviewed "Warning: “continue” targeting switch is equivalent to “break”. Did you mean to use “continue 2”?" at [this post in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54184707/warning-continue-targeting-switch-is-equivalent-to-break-did-you-mean-to-u) and tried both `composer update` and `composer self-update`.

I still get the `"continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"?` error.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this one is new in [php 7.3](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration73.incompatible.php)

you can try `composer self-update` or download the latest version of composer.phar.

If the error is thrown in a third-party library, you can hardly do more then opening tickets with them.