# phpunit is not running in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I tried to run phpunit with sample test but it was not executing. It shows NO TEST EXECUTED.

My default File contains ExampleTest.php and TestCase.php

> C:\xampp\htdocs\amber_fuel>phpunit PHP Warning:  "continue" targeting
>   switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"? in
>   C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php on line 277
>
> Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you
>   mean to use "continue 2"? in
>   C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php on line 277 PHP Warning: 
>   "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to
>   use "continue 2"? in C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php on
>   line 285
>
> Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you
>   mean to use "continue 2"? in
>   C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php on line 285
>       PHPUnit 3.7.21 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from C:\xampp\htdocs\amber_fuel\phpunit.xml

Time: 90 ms, Memory: 8.00MB

No tests executed!

Comment: What is the phpunit version? And what is your php version?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, it's highly recommended you upgrade your PHPUnit version and install packages via [Composer](http://getcomposer.org) instead of Pear

Comment: Looks like it's a PHP 7.3 change. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54184707/warning-continue-targeting-switch-is-equivalent-to-break-did-you-mean-to-u

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are running the global instance of PHPUnit on a Windows machine. I had the same problem, and the solution was extremely simple:

1. Use the local version of PHPUnit managed by Composer (which should be much newer than the global environment version of 3.7.21).
2. Use backslashes insteadof forward slashes when calling your test runner.

If I am in the root directory of my project for example, I would run 
`vendor\bin\phpunit`

Your tests should then run and print the results.

Comment: I am searching from two day but could not solve the problem, if I try to upgrade phpunit it say "mpdf/mpdf v7.1.5 requires php ^5.6 || ~7.0.0 || ~7.1.0 || ~7.2.0 -> your P
HP version (7.3.22) does not satisfy that requirement." But your solution save me now I can run my test by using backslashes instead of forward slashes. Thanks man

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're running it this way?

```
./vendor/bin/phpunit
```

Either enclose it in quotes like so:

```
"./vendor/bin/phpunit"
```

Or run it using powershell, by simply typing *powershell* from cmd then run it the regular way:

```
./vendor/bin/phpunit
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel uses

```
php artisan test .\tests\Feature\ExampleTest.php
```

for testing, not phpunit. https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/testing. I just ran into the same, tried to use old ways on a new tool :)