# Laravel install "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I've seen this error `"continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"?` in multiple questions both here and online-- but every solution simply says to upgrade `composer` to fix it. I've updated composer, updated laravel installer, and globally updated all packages, yet I still see the error:

```
➜ laravel -V
Laravel Installer 3.0.1

➜ composer self-update
You are already using composer version 1.10.1 (stable channel).

➜ php -v
PHP 7.3.16 (cli) (built: Mar 19 2020 11:19:09) ( NTS )

➜ composer global update
Changed current directory to ~/.composer
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files

➜ laravel new myprojectname
Crafting application...
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file


  [ErrorException]
  "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"?
```

Any other ideas what to check?

This is on Mac OSX Catalina

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54184707/warning-continue-targeting-switch-is-equivalent-to-break-did-you-mean-to-u)

Comment: @pr1nc3 no unfortunately all those solutions seem to be "upgrade composer" which I already did. Thanks

Comment: There is something missing here. With PHP 7.3, composer 1.10.1, and Laravel installer 3.0.1 I can't reproduce these results. See it [here](https://imgur.com/a/bF6VORR). Despite what the (wrong) answer below says, you do not need to downgrade to PHP 7.2 to work with the latest version of Laravel and/or composer. As you would imagine, that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: You'll need to add more details for anyone to take a guess. But without being able to repro the issue, it's hard. Just to make sure, clear composer cache (`clearcache`). What OS are you on?

Comment: Re: your edit. My screenshoot was taken on Mac as well. How are you installing PHP? Homebrew? Something besides the obvious is broken, because what you are doing should work. Cleared composer's cache?

Comment: @yivi thanks, that `clearcache` idea got me further along to the point that I could see the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up being a problem with some conflicting aliases in my `.zshrc` config.

`Composer` was aliased as `usr/local/bin/composer.phar`, so I moved that file to `~/.composer/vendor/bin/composer`, and deleted all the aliases for `laravel`, `lumen` and `composer` in my `.zshrc` file and removed and re-added the basic `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"` path as well.

This was helpful: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/sh-composer-command-not-found