# Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"? divi theme

Tags: wordpress

hi i just moved the wordpress theme files from hosting to local, but the error is like this. how to fix it?

I'm using the Divi theme

```
Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"? in /opt/lampp/htdocs/teswp/wp-content/themes/Divi/includes/builder/functions.php on line 5684
```

Comment: Have you made any changes to your  Divi theme ?

Comment: no, I just cloned the theme from my hosting to my local machine

Comment: Try running `composer self-update` in your theme.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54184707/warning-continue-targeting-switch-is-equivalent-to-break-did-you-mean-to-u

Comment: not work for me