# How can I check which version of composer an app was built with?

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm trying to dockerise an app that was handed down to me from other company and am running into the problem described here: [Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54184707/warning-continue-targeting-switch-is-equivalent-to-break-did-you-mean-to-u)

I figured the first thing I should ensure is to have the correct version of composer. If I am wrong I will wholeheartedly welcome an advise.

Comment: What makes you think that this is a problem of Composer? Usually, such a warning is thrown if the PHP version does not match

Comment: The error is completely unrelated to the Composer's version. Also, there is usually zero reasons to check which version of composer was used to generate the original `composer.lock` file. If your version of composer is not compatible, you'd get an error to that effect (not the one you mention in your question, but one complaining about the `plugin-api-version`.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two methods.

**#1** If the `composer.lock` file exists, there is a mention of Composer version, for example at very end should be something like:

```
    "plugin-api-version": "2.2.0"
}
```

> (Which means Composer 2.2.0 obviously.)

**#2** If Composer-API is used as dependency, another way would be checking `composer.json` file, simply search for composer mentions there.